# Robot_localization diagnostics topic question

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently attempting to fine-tune an instance of (ekf) robot_localization using gps and single imu devices.  In doing so, the diagnostic topic lists:

```
- 
    level: 1
    name: ekf_localization: Filter diagnostic updater
    message: Potentially erroneous data or settings detected for a robot_localization state estimation node.
    hardware_id: none
    values: 
      - 
        key: imu0_pose_covariance
        value: The covariance at position (35), which corresponds to YAW variance, was zero. This will be replaced with a small value to maintain filter stability, but should be corrected at the message origin node.
  -
```

The location of “position (35)” YAW covariance eludes me in attempting to revise the value.  I've searched all the code for robot_localization and the code for the Phidgets 1044 imu to no  avail.  The ekf_localization launch file initial covariance is set (currently  at a non-zero value of 0.035).  The  "message origin node" is the elusive part.

Aside from the ekf_localization initial_estimate_covariance, is there anywhere left to look for modification?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

B2256

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233857/robot_localization-diagnostics-topic-question/) by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's complaining about your IMU messages, not your `r_l` configuration. Do a `rostopic echo` on your IMU data, and I'm guessing you'll find that the value in the last index of your orientation covariance is 0.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-05-08**:
Yes, it appears that you're correct as all the orientation_covariances are zero at this timestamp.  It is still unclear where to modify this value? Any advice?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-05-08**:
Which ROS package are you using for the IMU?

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-05-09**:
I'm using the ROS driver phidgets_imu by Ivan Dryanovski.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-05-09**:
That driver doesn't appear to support orientation. I think it only gives angular velocity, linear acceleration, and raw mag data. You need to use another IMU filter like `imu_filter_madgwick` to get the orientation data, then feed that topic into `r_l`.

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-05-11**:
It turns out that I was using imu_filter _madgwick indirectly. An earlier answer by Tom mentioned using dynamic_reconfigure with this driver; that was successful.  Thank you as always.